# Jooq deserialize JSON date to java.time.LocalDateTime incorrectly without annotation @JsonDeserialize

Tags: java, jooq

Is possible to remove annotation like:

```
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    protected LocalDateTime createTime;
```

from code, and create some one place configuration in springboot?

Problem occure, when i try to get data from database this way:

```
public SomeDataMasterDto findById(Integer id) {
        SomeDataMasterDto someDataMasterDto = dslContext
                .select(jsonObject(
                        key("id").value(SOME_DATA_MASTER.ID),
                        key("createTime").value(SOME_DATA_MASTER.CREATE_TIME),
                        key("orderTime").value(SOME_DATA_MASTER.ORDER_TIME),
                        key("someDataOtherDtos").value(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(
                                key("id").value(SOME_DATA_OTHER.ID),
                                key("createTime").value(SOME_DATA_OTHER.CREATE_TIME),
                                key("offerType").value(SOME_DATA_OTHER.OFFER_TYPE),
                        )).absentOnNull())
                ))
                .from(SOME_DATA_MASTER)
                .leftJoin(SOME_DATA_OTHER).on(SOME_DATA_OTHER.SOME_DATA_MASTER_ID.eq(SOME_DATA_MASTER.ID))
                .where(SOME_DATA_MASTER.ID.eq(id))
                .groupBy(SOME_DATA_MASTER.ID)
                .fetchOneInto(SomeDataMasterDto.class);

        return someDataMasterDto;
}
```

I try override ObjectMapper in springboot like:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonObjectMapper {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

        return mapper;
    }
}
```

but i think, that jooq use own created objectMapper. I tried also other examples from stackoverflow (with `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`, `DateFormatter`...) but without success.

Environment:

- jdk 11
- jooq 3.14.4
- springboot 2.4.1
- postgresql 12.2

Comment: What do you mean by "incorrectly"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using this approach as it was recommended [in jOOQ 3.14 to use SQL/JSON to nest collections with jOOQ](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/10/09/nesting-collections-with-jooq-3-14s-sql-xml-or-sql-json-support/)? If you're ready to upgrade to jOOQ 3.15, the SQL/JSON serialisation bits can be abstracted [using the new standard SQL `MULTISET` support](https://blog.jooq.org/2021/07/06/jooq-3-15s-new-multiset-operator-will-change-how-you-think-about-sql/), in case of which you can write:

```sql
SomeDataMasterDto result =
ctx.select(
       SOME_DATA_MASTER.ID,
       SOME_DATA_MASTER.CREATE_TIME,
       SOME_DATA_MASTER.ORDER_TIME,
       multisetAgg(
           SOME_DATA_OTHER.ID,
           SOME_DATA_OTHER.CREATE_TIME,
           SOME_DATA_OTHER.OFFER_TYPE,
       ).as("someDataOtherDtos")
           .convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(SomeDataOtherDto::new)))
   )
   .from(SOME_DATA_MASTER)
   .leftJoin(SOME_DATA_OTHER)
       .on(SOME_DATA_OTHER.SOME_DATA_MASTER_ID.eq(SOME_DATA_MASTER.ID))
   .where(SOME_DATA_MASTER.ID.eq(id))
   .groupBy(SOME_DATA_MASTER.ID)
   .fetchOne(Records.mapping(SomeDataMasterDto::new));
```

The above mapping approach is using the [new ad-hoc conversion features](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/) and is assuming your DTOs are immutable objects (e.g. Java 16 records). You can still use the reflection methods, if you prefer that, using `into(Class<?>)`

See also:

- [`MULTISET_AGG`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/multiset-agg-function/)
- [`MULTISET` value constructor](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/multiset-value-constructor/)
- [Ad-hoc type conversion](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/)